# R cmd check: how to avoid error for examples when using internal functions

Tags: r, package

I am developing a small R package to define custom color palettes. I have two functions that I expose to the user with the `@export` roxygen/doxygen tag. Both of these functions rely on an internal function, which I marked with `@keywords internal`. When I run `devtools::check()` I get an error that the examples provided for my two external functions could not be run because the internal function was not found. This happens whether or not I prefix the internal function with `my_package:::my_internal_function` or not (just `my_internal_function`). I found [this blogpost](https://statisticaloddsandends.wordpress.com/2021/06/10/documentation-for-internal-functions/) which states that the example code can be wrapped into a `\dontrun{}`, which is what I do to avoid the error from R CMD check. however, this seems a bit of a hack. so what is the preferred way to deal with examples that rely on an internal function?

Update:

- I cannot reproduce the problem anymore :-/ sorry for the bother, now it seems to run without issues. I don't know what is different now, but kind of problem solved.

Comment: can you share what your code looks like ? `\dontrun{}` isn't a hack and can be useful but you should be able to run example code with an internal function

Comment: I'm confused. "Both of these functions rely on an internal function" OK, that doesn't matter. They should just get it from the package namespace, which is where they are defined as well. "examples provided for my two external functions could not be run because the internal function was not found" Why are your examples calling an internal function directly?

Comment: I'm with @Roland, examples should showcase how your functions can be used by the users. You shouldn't be calling internal functions in your examples. If they are of use to the user you should export them.

Comment: Regarding the error you get when using `:::` is your package installed on your PC before running check?